# Managing application environments in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops

I need advice from experienced GCP users. I have a web SaaS app with a front-end written with Flutter and a backend on GCP. It uses Cloud Run services, Cloud Workflows, Firestore, Cloud Storage and GCP AI Platform.

Each of these services has its own service account.

Flutter front-end requests Cloud Run APIs directly - these are front-end request handlers, and there are no others.

I need to deploy copies of this SaaS app as a new GCP project as a new environment to separate production, staging and development environments.

Thus far, I have used custom Python scripts for that. The script creates a new project, deploys containers for Cloud Run, workflows, changes endpoint addresses for the front-end, etc. Yet, it has become too heavy, and I suspect there must be a better way to manage environments (create and delete application copies) in GCP. Could you please suggest the better/proper way to do that with the GCP?

Comment: Have you considered Terraform? They are the gold standard today. Very well supported, large user base, has reasonably good documentation, and is an excellent toolset overall.

Comment: @John Hanley, I have been looking at it but perhaps not deeply enough. From what you are saying about being a well-supported gold standard I guess it is worth the effort to investigate it and apply it to our needs. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @John Hanley

---

> They are the gold standard today. Very well supported, large user base, has reasonably good documentation, and is an excellent toolset overall.

---

You can manage your infrastructure effectively and consistently with Terraform on Google Cloud due to its automation, scalability, consistency, and adaptability. Your operations become more streamlined, manual duties are decreased, and you can concentrate more on application development and business logic.

---

You may also check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform) for Terraform on Google Cloud.